# Azure DevOps Powershell on remote machine issue with dollar sign in secret

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I've spent quite a number of hours researching and testing on this but no luck...

We have an Azure DevOps release pipeline that uses secret variables passed into Powershell scripts. That tends to work rather well.

We've recently started using the "Powershell on target machines" task to run Powershell remotely. That has worked pretty well, with one big exception: The cursed dollar sign.

Here's the scenario:

Password stored in an Azure Devops secret variable. Secret variable is referenced in the "Powershell on target machines" task.

So far, so good.

Now put a dollar sign ($) in the value of the password secret variable.

The dollar sign is interpreted as the beginning of a Powershell variable name, so in the end, the value that is passed around is ultimately chopped off to be the part of the variable before the dollar sign. It's a nightmare to research, because secret values cannot be shown.

We've tried many, many things, including single quotes, double quotes, no quotes, backticks, and pretty much everything that stackoverflow and others have to offer.

In short, we just need to pass a password safely into a Powershell script that is executed on a remote machine on the domain. We have a lot of flexibility within that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm.. I tried with my pipeline. Adding a backtick works to me. I set my variable `abc\`$dasod0as` and the Powershell scrip `echo $(password)` outputs abc$dasod0as

Comment: Which powershell task type did you use? The one that gives me trouble is "Powershell on target machines".

Comment: I'm finding that we may have a different issue that is causing misdirection on the cause. Working through it now.